# MySQL event or trigger to automatically update a value 30 minutes after last modify

Tags: mysql

I have in my DB (`db_test`) a table (`tb_test`) with 3 columns (`id`, `test_field`, `timestamp_ins`, `timestamp_mod`).

`id` is the 'primary key' with auto-increment attribute;

`test_field` is a char(1) that can contains only 2 values ('N' or 'S');

`timestamp_ins` is a datetime with current timestamp (not updating);

`timestamp_mod` is a datetime with current timestamp set to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

I would like `test_field` automatically returns to default value ('N') 30 minutes after last modify of record indicated in `timestamp_mod` value.

I'm not expert in mysql, so I need help about this.
Is it possible using phpMyAdmin on a XAMPP virtual server?

--UPDATE--
Solved with this syntax:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS test_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
UPDATE ni0y2__test
SET test_field = DEFAULT
WHERE test_field < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Only one doubt:
can this event make my DB performances worse?

Comment: Use the Event Scheduler to run a query every few minutes. It should assign the default value to all rows where `timestamp_mod < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`

Comment: An alternative would be to use a virtual generated column; though I don't think the data changes enough for you to realize the benefit.  I think the scheduled job is likely a better option.  Especially if this is to be an indexed column

Answer (score 0):

I prefer putting the onus on the reader, not the table:

```
SELECT  IF (timestamp_mod < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,
            'N',
            test_field)  AS funky_field
    FROM tb_test;
```

`EVENTs` have some overhead.  Also, the above method will change at precisely 30 minutes; any attempt at using `EVENT` will be only approximately 30.

You *could* "hide" the `IF(...)` from the users by using a `VIEW` or Stored Function or a `GENERATED` column.